# Spring ResponsEntity body contains extra json with timestamp, status and more

Tags: java, json, spring

We have an REST endpoint that will add a new empty ingredient to an existing meal:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Object> add(@RequestBody final Meal meal) throws URISyntaxException
{
    Optional<Meal> optionalMeal = mealRepository.findById(meal.getId());
    if (!optionalMeal.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            .body(MessageUtil.parse(MSG_404_MEAL, meal.getId() + ""));
    }

    Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
    ingredient.setMeal(optionalMeal.get());
    ingredientRepository.saveAndFlush(ingredient);

    ResponseEntity re = ResponseEntity
        .created(RequestUtil.getResourceURI(ingredient.getId()))
        .body(ingredient);

    return re;
}
```

Ingredient is an entity class with some fields:

```
public class Ingredient implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private Meal meal;
    private Grocery grocery;
    private Float amount;

    ...
}
```

RequestUtil takes care of creating the URI where the newly created resource is to be found:

```
public class RequestUtil
{
    public static URI getResourceURI(int id) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        final String url = RequestUtil.getCurrentRequest().getRequestURL().toString();
        final String req = RequestUtil.omitLast(url);

        return new URI(req + "get/" + id);
    }

    public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest() 
    {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        return ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
    }

    public static String omitLast(final String url) {
        return url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }
}
```

The http status code and resource URI end up correctly in the response headers, but the body contains two JSONs:

```
{
  "id": 407,
  "meal": {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "New Meal",
    "active": true
  },
  "grocery": null,
  "amount": null,
  "bought": false
} {
  "timestamp": "2018-08-29T19:25:31.466+0000",
  "status": 201,
  "error": "Created",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/ingredient/add"
}
```

Our javascript code does not expect this extra data and fails with

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 114 of the JSON data
```

Using a debugger, we can see that by the time the code reaches the return statement in add(), the ResponseEntity does not contain this extra data. Can someone explain where it comes from, and how we stop it from polluting the response?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please, take a look at the _Network_ tab in the devtools and post the exact response body. The code posted below the text _but the body contains two JSONs_ text is not a [valid](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) JSON

Comment: Any chance that there is an extra servlet filter configured which adds extra JSON to the response in case it sees a 201 status code ?

Comment: @lealceldeiro That's exactly the problem. The two concatenated JSONs are directly copied from the response as seen in my browser's Network tab.

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar The project is a spring boot application, so there's Spring, but nothing else.

Comment: With spring boot there is still the usual java webapp stack, including servlet filters. spring boot might actually add a bunch of them in its default configuration

Comment: I have not found a class ``RequestUtil`` with a method ``getResourceURI``. In which package can I find this class?

Comment: RequestUtil is a class we created to return the URI of the resource created in case that response is a http 201 Created. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Hello @Mr.Wrong
I am having the same issue, did you ever find the cause of this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an old version of spring boot, I had to add in my **application.properties**
`server.error.include-message=never`
or if you're using **application.yml**, add

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: never
```

It worked for me